# How do I calculate a bounding box for leaflet from a set of points in d3

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I'm adding points to a leaflet map from a d3/crossfilter data set (loaded from a CSV). After the points are added, I want to zoom/pan so that the point are in view. What's the easiest way to do this... I'm thinking I could write some min/max longitude/latitude functions and then loop through the data set to create a bounding box to use with map.fitBound, but wondering if there is an easier way...

code snippet:-

```
function updateMapData() {
    g.selectAll("*").remove();
    var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
        .data(byID.top(Infinity))
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
            .style("stroke", "black")  
            .style("opacity", .95) 
            .style("fill", "black")
            .attr("r", 4);

    map.on("viewreset", updateMap);
    updateMap(); 

    function updateMap() {
        feature.attr("transform", 
        function(d) { 
            return "translate("+ 
                map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).x +","+ 
                map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).y +")";
            }
        )
    };
};
```

Comment: You could construct a polygon from the points and then fit the map to that.

Comment: In the end, I just run the following (but I'm still wondering if I should be using geoJSON or d3.geo instead...):- 

    'bounds = [];
    byID.top(Infinity).forEach(function (d) {
        bounds.push(d.LatLng);
    });  
    map.fitBounds(bounds);'

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I just ran the following (but I'm still wondering if there is an easier way, or if I should be using geoJSON or d3.geo instead...)

```
bounds = [];
byID.top(Infinity).forEach(function (d) {
    bounds.push(d.LatLng);
});  
map.fitBounds(bounds, {pan: {animate: true, duration: 1.5, easeLinearity: 0.25}});
```